# SQOOP --export-dir: command not found

Tags: hive, teradata, sqoop

Here is my Sqoop Script

```
trap "" 1
declare -i RC=0
set -x -u
declare -l DB=MY_DB
declare -l TBL=MY_TABLE

        date
        time sqoop export \
        -D mapreduce.job.queuename=default \
        -D teradata.db.input.method=split.by.hash \
        --libjars=/sqoopLib/lib \
        --connect jdbc:teradata://ServerURL/Database=$DB \
        --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
        --username xxxxxx  --password-file /location/passwordfile \
        --table $TBL \
        --export-dir /HiveTableLocation/$TBL || RC=$?
        --batch

date
exit $RC
```

Every thing looks fine connection and everything and locations are also valid.
But it throws  --export-dir: command not found  with RC =127

Comment: what is this `RC=$?` for? what are you trying to do?

Comment: As you can see in the script RC is defined for Reason code, a code returned after execution of each command.Also I have mentioned this is a SQOOP script that means SQOOPing data from hive to teradata.